MultipleChoiceField doesn't get populated from model
Given the model field:
categories = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
And the form field:
class ArtworkDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Categories",required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=Artwork.CATEGORIES)


The result:
I can select one or more of the choices from the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget, save the form, and the choices get saved in the categories model field. All good. But the next time I execute the form for the same record, the widget isn't populated with those choices. All of the other fields are getting correctly populated.
